# Full-text search on App Engine with Whoosh

Tags: python, google-app-engine, full-text-search, whoosh

I need to do full text searching with Google App Engine. I found the project [Whoosh](http://github.com/tallstreet/Whoosh-AppEngine/tree/master) and it works really well, as long as I use the App Engine Development Environement... When I upload my application to App Engine, I am getting the following TraceBack. For my tests, I am using the example application provided in this project. Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

```
<type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: cannot import name loads
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/myapp/1.334374478538362709/hello.py", line 6, in <module>
    from whoosh import store
  File "/base/data/home/apps/myapp/1.334374478538362709/whoosh/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from whoosh.index import open_dir, create_in
  File "/base/data/home/apps/myapp/1.334374478538362709/whoosh/index.py", line 31, in <module>
    from whoosh import fields, store
  File "/base/data/home/apps/myapp/1.334374478538362709/whoosh/store.py", line 27, in <module>
    from whoosh import tables
  File "/base/data/home/apps/myapp/1.334374478538362709/whoosh/tables.py", line 43, in <module>
    from marshal import loads
```

Here is the import I have in my Python file.

```
# Whoosh ----------------------------------------------------------------------
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'utils')))
from whoosh.fields import Schema, STORED, ID, KEYWORD, TEXT
from whoosh.index import getdatastoreindex
from whoosh.qparser import QueryParser, MultifieldParser
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 7):

You could probably solve your problems by downloading and using [Whoosh-Appengine](http://github.com/tallstreet/Whoosh-AppEngine/tree/master), the Whoosh version that's specifically targeted to working with Google App Engine.

Comment: I am using that version... it works only in the Development Env.

Comment: Bear in mind that even if you fix this issue, Whoosh-Appengine just uses the datastore as a file store, and doesn't respect the 1MB limit - so it may not work for any substantial amount of data.

Comment: There is now experimental support for gae inside of the current Whoosh release. See `whoosh/filedb/gae.py` in the 2.4.1 release.

Answer (score 4):

This is an official example about implementing full text search: http://code.google.com/p/guestbook-example-appengine-full-text-search/

I'm currently reading through it as I'm in the need of implementing it, maybe it will help others also.

Answer (score 3):

The marshal module is not supported on app engine. It is there, but it is empty. That marshal is working as normal in the dev. environment has been [registered as an issue](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=892).

See [the documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#Pure_Python).

You could try the following to monkeypatch the marshal module. Put the following code before you do any other imports:

```
import pickle
import marshal
marshal.loads = pickle.loads
marshal.dumps = pickle.dumps # I assume it needs dumps also
```

I have not tried this, so I have absolutely no idea if it will work! Also be aware that pickle loads/dumps is slower than marshal loads/dumps.

Comment: In my testing for App Engine I have noticed pickle (rather than cPickle) is sometimes more than 10x slower than marshal.

Answer (score 1):

See comment #71 here: 
http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=217&q=Whoosh&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Owner%20Summary%20Log%20Component#c71:

It's not my tool, but it says:

I have created a full text search api by porting http://whoosh.ca/ so it is avaliable
on AppEngine. (it stores the index in the datastore)

You can download it from http://github.com/tallstreet/Whoosh-AppEngine/tree/master

It includes all of Whooshes features including:

1 Pythonic API. 
 2 Fielded indexing and search.
 3 Fast indexing and retrieval
 4 Pluggable scoring algorithm (including BM25F), text analysis, storage, posting
format, etc.
 5 Powerful query language parsed by pyparsing.
 6 Pure Python spell-checker