# Jinja2 in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, caching, jinja2

I have started using [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/2/documentation/) as my templating engine on Google App Engine (in Python).

My question is this: Will bytecode caching work in production? It is working very well on the development server, but I read somewhere that bytecode caching depends on the `marshal` module, which is not supported in App Engine. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028992/full-text-search-on-app-engine-with-whoosh/1029099#1029099) to a different question provides a possible solution by changing `marshal` to use `pickle` methods. Has anyone tried this?

In general, is there anything else that I should take into consideration when using Jinja2 with App Engine?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: It turns out that `pickle` can't be used for code objects (that's why Jinja2 uses `marshal` to persist its compiled template bytecode). `marshal` is available in the local development environment, but it is an empty module in the deployed GAE environment (see http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#Pure_Python).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rodrigo Moraes created some special loaders for Jinja2 under GAE, see [here](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-python/browse_thread/thread/04d4bf3dd615ed1e/2907cdeff922710c). It's not bytecode caching but it precompiles all templates to Python so you avoid the Jinja2 parsing overhead.

Note that (from [this GAE page](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/)):

> compiled application code is cached
>   for rapid responses to web requests

Comment: I'm just going to go with un-cached templates for now. I'll take a closer look when I have more time to delve into the code. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 9):

Jinja2 is now included in GAE. Apparently you need to migrate your app to Python 2.7.

In app.yaml add

```
libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: "2.6"
```

Here is the source of this information: http://blog.notdot.net/2011/11/Migrating-to-Python-2-7-part-2-Webapp-and-templates

Answer (score 1):

According to the [What's New in Python 2.7 docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python27/newin27#Bytecode_Upload), with Python 2.7 you can also upload .pyc files.

> Can upload .pyc files, but not in combination with .py files. However, you can upload .zip files containing .py or .pyc files (or a combination).