# Displaying Python values in HTML

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine

How do I display the value of a python variable (in this case it is the key of my Entity class) in html?

```
from google.appengine.ext import db

class Entity(db.Expando):
    pass

e = Entity()    
e.put()         # id is assigned
k = e.key()     # key is complete
id = k.id()     # system assigned id

html='''
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <label>Key: %(k) </label>
        <br>            
    </body>
</html>
'''
```

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/handlingforms

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
import cgi

class Entity(db.Expando):
    pass

e = Entity()    
e.put()         # id is assigned
k = e.key()     # key is complete
id = k.id()     # system assigned id

html="""
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <label>Key: %s </label>
        <br>            
    </body>
</html>""" % (cgi.escape(k))
```

I would seriously advise you to use templates though it makes your life much easier.

With a template your solution would be something like this:

```
class Entity(db.Expando):
pass

e = Entity()    
e.put()         # id is assigned
k = e.key()     # key is complete
id = k.id()     # system assigned id

template = jinja_environment.get_template('templates/myTemplate')
self.response.write(template.render({'key_val':k}))
```

and the Mytemplate.html file would look like:

```
 <html>
   <head></head>
    <body>
     <label>{{key_val}}</label>
     <br>            
    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for your reply and advice. I'll learn and use jinja2. But since I'm new to both Python and GAE, I thought it might be simpler for me to paste the html in the python script.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know much about google app engine, but in Python, there are two ways:

```
html='''
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <label>Key: %(k)s </label>
        <br>            
    </body>
</html>
''' % locals() # Substitude %(k)s for your variable k
```

Second:

```
html='''
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <label>Key: {0[k]} </label>
        <br>            
    </body>
</html>
'''.format(locals())
```

Actually, there is the third way, which I prefer because it is explicit:

```
html='''
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <label>Key: {0} </label>
        <br>            
    </body>
</html>
'''.format(k)
```

Comment: Nice optons - also see one below which shows how to escape HTML values explicitly to prevent cross-site scripting attacks.

Answer (score 1):

Your immediate output could be:

```
<label>Key: {{k}} </label>
```

First have a look at a basic django template

[getting started with templates](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/templates)

Then possibly have a look at jinja2

[jinja2 templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365774/jinja2-in-google-app-engine)